# EF Core : Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to get total number of user playlist episodes so I use this query

```
var a = _context.Playlists
                .Include(e => e.SeriesPlaylists)
                .ThenInclude(e => e.Series.Seasons)
                .ThenInclude(e => e.Episodes)
                .Where(e => e.UserId == guidUserId)
                .SelectMany(e => e.SeriesPlaylists).Select(e => e.Series).SelectMany(e => e.Seasons, (p, c) => c.Episodes).Sum(e => e.Count);
```

but I got this error :

'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'

I know it is impossible to use count in sum expression in sql
is there any way to get total number f episodes ?

here is my model :

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : AuditableEntity
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

public class SeriesPlaylist 
{
        public Guid SeriesId { get; set; }
        public Series Series { get; set; }
        public Guid PlaylistId { get; set; }
        public Playlist Playlist { get; set; }
}

public class Series : BaseEntity
{
        public ICollection<Season> Seasons { get; set; }

}

  public class Season : BaseEntity
{
        public ICollection<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
}

public class Episode : BaseEntity
{

        public Season Season { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EpisodeUserRate> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Include` is needed only when you actually fetch the related data, here you need to count it only, so it's redundant.
What's wrong in your query is the use of `.Sum(e => e.Count)`. The correct query should be like this:

```
var a = _context.Playlists
                .Where(e => e.UserId == guidUserId)
                .SelectMany(e => e.SeriesPlaylists
                                  .Select(e => e.Series)
                                  .SelectMany(e => e.Seasons)
                                  .SelectMany(e => e.Episodes))
                .Count();
```